# Ask about the Website or Books about physics from A-Z

Tags: homework-and-exercises, resource-recommendations

I am a middle school student and I want to learn more about physics from A - Z but I don't know any book or website that is useful. Can you share me some suggestions?

Comment: You would have to be more specific about what you want to learn, or at least where you'd like to start. There is already a community book recommendation thread [here](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/12175/book-recommendations).

Answer (score 0):

Why not ask your teacher? He would better know how difficult the book can be. Or go to your local library, mostly they have a collection of books about physics and you find out which one you like. It is same years ago my kid used PHYSICS from Douglas C. Giancoli, it uses math not too much especially no calculus and covers large parts of physics, so I would recommend it if you are 14++